# Generate Observable Array using the original Array itself

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service (**MessageService**) that emits some messages based on some other app events.
Then, I have a component **MessagesComponent** and I'd like to render all the messages that were emitted by my Service. My approach is to use an **Observable<Message[]>** to store and reactively update the UI every time a new Message arrives.
Here's my working solution

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  template: `
    <h2>Received messages</h2>
    <ol>
      <li class="message" *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
        {{ message }}
      </li>
    </ol>
  `,
  styles: [``]
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  messages$ = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);
  
  constructor(private messagesService: MessagesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messagesService.message$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        switchMap((message: Message) =>
          this.messages$.pipe(
            take(1),
            map((all: Message[]) => {
              return [...all, message];
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((messages: Message[]) => {
        this.messages$.next(messages);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Right now, I start with an empty **BehaviorSubject** array to store all the messages. Then, in the **ngOnInit** hook, I subscribe to the **MessagesService's message$** and after a new emission I am combining what I have in the **BehaviorSubject** with the new message thus emitting a new array with all the items.
My solution seems to work, but I'd like to avoid the subscription in **NgOnit** (if possible). I was thinking in something like this

```
messages$: Observable<Message[]> = this.messagesService.message$.pipe(
        switchMap((message: Message) =>
          this.messages$.pipe(
            startWith([]),
            take(1),
            map((all: Message[]) => [...all, message])
          )
        )
      );
```

I'm trying to use the array itself as part of their own initialization using **SwitchMap** + **StartWith** however it doesn't seems to work, so I'm looking for some other ideas :)

Oh, the Message type is just a simple interface with some properties.

```
export interface Message {
  id: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Comment: can you explain in short about your use case ?

Comment: First paragraph :)

Comment: Ok, I think you do not need messages$ of compoennt.ts , You can use service message$ directly in component template for your ngFor loop.

Comment: No, not really. Service's message$ emits a single message (it's not an array). That's why I'm using the BehaviourSubject in the component, to store all the service emissions as an array allowing me to iterate the array in the  template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator to accumulate state.  It will have access to the previous emission and you can build upon that.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  
  messages$ = this.messagesService.message$.pipe(
    scan((all, message) => all.concat(message), [])
  );

  constructor(private messagesService: MessagesService) { }

}
```

When `scan` receives an emission from `mesageService.message$`, it will run the function

```
(all, message) => all.concat(message)
```

and emit the result.  `message` is the value received from the service. The first time, `all` has a value of our initial seed value (`[]`).  After that, it is the previously emitted value;

Notice the component code is greatly simplified; you don't need: Subject, BehaviorSubject, subscription, ngOnInit, ngOnDestroy, takeUntil, switchMap, nor take :-)

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71361532?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for!